# How to fix the Items per page to 5 and only show navigation arrows in mat table

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material

I want to show only 5 items per page and disable pageSizeOptions but display the navigations so that use can browse through all pages by that navigation keys only.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5puR.jpg)

Comment: It would have been better to understand if the question mentioned that it is about Angular Material's Grid Paginator, even better if you could try looking into its API options listed here (https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only:

<mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" showFirstLastButtons>

You can use any number instead of 5 as per your need. But in this case user wont be able to change items per page and height of the table will be fixed.